# Since I execute 'stty erase ~' I can't type / anymore in Putty

Tags: keyboard, putty, stty

Yesterday I was fed up with being forced to type <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to erase character in Putty, because a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> was printing a `~`.
I found some info on internet saying you should type `stty erase ~`, or at least that how I understand it.
Since then when I type on <kbd>/</kbd> it send a <kbd>←</kbd> to the terminal and I'm not even capable to copy/paste in my putty.
Does anyone has a good idea to save me ?

**Note**:
<kbd>/</kbd> is still working in binary like `vi` or `more` but not in `bash` (where I typed the command).

Additional info:

```
bash-3.2# stty -a
speed 38400 baud; 55 rows; 210 columns
eucw 1:1:0:0, scrw 1:1:0:0:
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = /; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>
eol2 = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; dsusp = ^Y; reprint = ^R
discard = ^O; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V
-parenb -parodd cs8 -cstopb -hupcl cread -clocal -parext
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iuclc
ixon -ixany -ixoff -imaxbel
isig icanon -xcase echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh
-tostop -echoctl -echoprt -echoke -flusho -pending -iexten
opost -olcuc onlcr -ocrnl -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel tab3
```

**Edit 2**:
Also `stty -g` provide a string usable by other `stty` so if you have a working command elsewhere you can export the result of one to import it to the buggy one.

Comment: Maybe ~ got expanded as /path/to/your/home/dir and the erase character got set to the first character of that.

Comment: Type `stty erase '~'` (with single quotes).

Comment: <3 I LOVE YOU <3 you should post it as an answer

Comment: Now that it is fixed, you can also consider configuring what key putty sends when you hit the backspace key as an alternative to adapting the shell to putty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unquoted `~` expands to `/path/to/your/home/dir` in most shells.

The [stty man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/stty.html) doesn't say what it does when the argument to `erase` is something other than a single character or `undef` or `^` followed by a character, but it looks like your `stty` uses the first character of the argument string.

Type `stty erase '~'` (with the single quotes). It's good practice to *always* quote the argument, because some shells treat `^` as the pipe symbol.